# How to form connection between HSQLDB and C# .net?

Tags: hsqldb

How to form connection between HSQLDB and C# .net ? I  have already looked at SharpHSQL and H2Sharp but not able to connect the HSQLDB.

Comment: Why did you not mark any of the solutions as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

try like this:
Make sure you've already add hsqldb.dll, IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll, IKVM.OpenJDK.Jdbc.dll as reference.
If you don't have the IKVM library, you can download [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ikvm/files/ikvm/7.2.4630.5/).

At your C#:

```
using java.sql; //add this.
```

for create a connection:

```
private Connection GetConnection()
    {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver());
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://[host]/[db name]", "[username]", "[password]");
        return conn;
    }
```

how to use it:

```
public void LoadSetting(String userId)
    {
        Connection conn = null;
        try
        {
            //Connect it!
            conn = GetConnection();

            string query = "SELECT A.* FROM table A";

            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next())
            {
               //Get Query Result
               Console.WriteLn(rs.getString("COL1"));
               Console.WriteLn(rs.getString("COL2"));
            }
         }

         //Close the Connection
         finally
         {
            if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed())
            {
                conn.close();
                conn = null;
            }
         }
     }
```

Hope this help.
Cheers...

Comment: That's indeed a working solution if you don't have a requirement that all the code is native C#. Thank you for the idea. Also you might have to add some more IKVM dll dependencies apart from the two you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Basic steps:

1. Download [IKVM.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IKVM/8.1.5717) and [HyperSQL](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb/files/) (=HSQLDB) driver.
2. Convert HSQLDB Java driver to .NET DLL using IKVM.NET to create a **hsqldb.dll**
3. Add compile time dependencies to your C# project:

- hsqldb.dll
- IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll
- IKVM.OpenJDK.Jdbc.dll

4. Add runtime dependencies when running your C# program:

- IKVM.OpenJDK.Localedata.dll
- IKVM.OpenJDK.Text.dll
- IKVM.OpenJDK.Util.dll
- IKVM.Runtime.dll

5. Add connection string to your app.config :

```
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="HyperSQL"
        connectionString="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9999/xdb;user=SA;password=;" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

6. C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
 
namespace HyperSQL
{
    class Program
    {
        readonly static string CONNECTION_STRING = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HyperSQL"].ConnectionString;
        const string SQL = "SELECT * FROM customer";
 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver());
            using (java.sql.Connection conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
            {
                java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
                using (java.sql.ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery())
                {
                    while (rs.next())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"ID={rs.getInt("id")}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"NAME={rs.getString("name")}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"AGE={rs.getInt("age")}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"ADDRESS={rs.getString("address")}");
                        Console.WriteLine($"SALARY={rs.getInt("salary")}");
 
                        Console.WriteLine("------------------");
                    }
                }
            }
 
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Here my detailed tutorial [how to connect to HyperSQL from C#](http://nikolaiklimov.de/query-java-HyperSQL-database-with-csharp/)

Comment: The link for the tutorial is no longer valid, could you please update it. Thanks,