# Connect hsqldb using c#

Tags: c#, hsqldb

I have a tool that uptades a local hsql database on my machine.My question is how can i connect to the that hsql database using Visual Studio,get the information and insert it to my own sql database(if possible).I tried using the code from this link : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119284/how-to-form-connection-between-hsqldb-and-c-sharp-net), but i dont understand the part with

```
private Connection GetConnection()
    {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver());
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://[host]/[db name]", "[username]", "[password]");
        return conn;
    }
```

What is the purpose of the .getConnection.I dont understand what url,username or password to give it.

Comment: It is the connection string which you have to configure. host  will be 'localhost', db name is the database name in hsqldb. username and password are the login credentials that you use to connect to hsql database.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but now when i try to connect, i keep getting this error: Method 'getParentLogger' in type 'org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver' from assembly 'Org.Hsqldb, Version=1.8.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=05732303801b208f' does not have an implementation.":"org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver

Comment: I have added the IKVM through the nuget package manager(version 8.0.5449)